# Is it necessary to use article before" law and order" in the given sentence below?

Tags: definite-articles

In india, Law and order is not as good as it should be and reason being this, The police never reaches in time to rescue the ones who need them most.

Comment: 'Law and order' is a standard phrase and doesn't need an article. However, there are several other grammatical errors in your sentence. I can't tell you what they are as this site doesn't allow proofreading, but you need to look carefully at capitalisation and punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

In this case "law and order" can be seen as one concept, and you can ask yourself whether it makes sense to consider it countable.

This chart would seem to indicate that "the law and order" isn't that uncommon.

[NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*%20law%20and%20order&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bof%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaintain%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaintaining%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brestore%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bof%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaintain%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bto%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmaintaining%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Band%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthat%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Ball%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Brestore%20law%20and%20order%3B%2Cc0)

Analyzing this particular phrase is a bit tricky for a number of reasons, both of the two terms individually can be countable or uncountable:

The legislature makes law. (uncountable)
The legislature makes laws. (countable)

What's also interesting is that Google NGram Viewer shows that treating "law and order" as two subjects is pretty much as common as treating it as one subject, as seen by verb inflection that follows (are/is):

[Link to NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=law%20and%20order%20is%2Claw%20and%20order%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claw%20and%20order%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Claw%20and%20order%20are%3B%2Cc0)

In your case I would personally use and recommend omitting the article and using "is" after the term:

> In india, law and order is...

However that's not to say that's the only acceptable way.